# Как запускать скрипт с последними изменениями без перезапуска VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, telebot

Пишу бота на PyTelegramBotAPI в VS Code Mac.
Когда запускаю скрипт, он успешно выполняется. При изменении кода выполняется всё равно первоначальный скрипт, пока не перезапущу VS Code через принудительное закрытие (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>). Если через "крестик" закрыть и открыть, при компиляции опять выполняется начальная версия скрипта даже если сохранять его вручную через <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

VS Code 1.67.2, Python 3.10, PyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: а если сам терминал перезапустить?

Comment: Ога, Kill terminal, а потом запуск скрипта запускает последнюю версию скрипта, спасибо! Но нельзя ли это как-то автоматизировать?

Comment: не знаю как именно работает запуск в конкретном случае, но есть подозрение, что бот запускается каждый раз параллельно причем новые версии должны падать - из-за монопольности бота (только один бот с указанным `token` может работать)

Comment: Файл сохранить нужно при запуске, или поставить автосохранение